# How i18n works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just need some information on the below code.

```
<span class="label"><a href="#home" class="link"><img src="img/homeicon.png" alt="homeicon"><!-- ko i18n:'home' --><!-- /ko --></a></span>
```

After inspecting the same code on the webpage it shows like this:

```
<span class="label"><a href="#home" class="link"><img src="img/homeicon.png" alt="homeicon"><!-- ko i18n:'home' -->Home<!-- /ko --></a></span>
```

The only difference is that after inspecting it is showing Home in between  and 
I have a question, why the below commented parts from the above code are still working ? Although, they are commented.

1. `<!-- ko i18n:'home' -->`
2. `<!-- /ko -->`

In the JavaScript file, the home in small caps is written like this:
"home": "Home"

Any changes made in "Home" will directly effect the code displayed after inspection.

Comment: Probably for use in knockout

Comment: Yes, there are used in knockout but how it works in html and how it is working in the above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referencing the string "Home" via the id in the comment, in this case 'home'.

If you go into the JS file and change it to:
`"home":"House"`
I'm guessing you'll see the rendered text change to `House`.

Looks like Knockout is parsing the page looking for the "ko i18n" comments and then inserting the proper text from the JS file.

Comment: Yes, if I change Home to House then the House is getting reflected on the Front-end.